# Docker Tomcat users configuration not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tomcat8

*Update: cleanup and directly indicate the problem and the solution.*

**PROBLEM:**

Docker-tomcat was properly installed and running, except for the 403 Access error in the Manager App. It also seems that my docker tomcat cannot find my tomcat-users.xml configuration.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to [Farhad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5867722/farhad-farahi) and [Sanket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7610918/sanket-d) for the answers.

**[Files]:**

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.11
MAINTAINER Borgy Manotoy <borgymanotoy@ujeaze.com>

# Update Apt and then install Nano editor (RUN can be removed)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nano \
&& mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/conf

# Copy configurations (Tomcat users, Manager app)
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/
```

**Tomcat Users Configuration (conf/tomcat-users.xml)**

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
</tomcat-users>
```

**Application Context (webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!--
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
  -->
</Context>
```

**[STEPS & COMMANDS]:**

1. Build Docker Image

   docker build -t borgymanotoy/my-tomcat-docker .
2. Run Image (my-tomcat-docker and set port to 8088)

   docker run --name my-tomcat-docker-container -p 8088:8080 -it -d borgymanotoy/my-tomcat-docker
3. Go to the container's bash (to check files inside the container thru bash)

   docker exec -it biyahe-tomcat-docker-container bash

Answer (score 17):

First you need to expose your application in the container, so you can connect to it from  dockerhost/network.

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8080 tomcat:8.5.11-jre8
```

You need to change 2 files in order to access the mangaer app from remote host. (Browser on Docker host is considered remote, only packets received on containers loopback are considered local for tomcat)

1. `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml` Note the commented section.

   ```
   <Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
   <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
            allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
   -->
   ```

Please note the commented section.

2. `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml` as you stated in the question.

   ```
   <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
             version="1.0">
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <role rolename="manager-script"/>
   <user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
   ```

In order to make changes to files in the container, You can try building your own image, but I suggest using docker volumes or bind mounts.

Also make sure you restart the container so the changes take effect.

Comment: Work for me, but you must restart your docker container with tomcat server

Answer (score 2):

Please specify the port when you do a `docker run` like (i believe `mine/tomcat-version` is your image name),

`docker run -p 8000:8080 -it -d --name MyContainerName mine/tomcat-version`

then access the manager page using,

```
http://<ipaddress>:8000/manager/html
```

To get the host ip address in docker to need to execute `docker-machine ip`

Addition info: You can also get into the container using below command,

`docker exec -it MyContainerName bash`  if you want to check different things like tomcat logs, conf files, etc.

Comment: I forgot to indicate that I already set the port to 8088 and assigned a name for the container. Thanks for the 'docker exec...' I needed this to work inside the container.

Comment: 403 error it seems it did not see the changes in my tomcat-users.xml, although it is already applied. I need to alter context.xml as indicated in farhad's answer in #1 and it works now :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Although this is quite late, I wanted to leave my 2 cents.

I took this solution to the next level by building a sample continuous integration system that deploys wars to the docker tomcat just by running `mvn clean install` via project IDE whilst having the docker tomcat container running.

- This solves the problem of having to restart tomcat-container every time a new build is available. Takes advantage of tomcat's auto-deploy
- Uses shared volume so that you can deploy multiple wars into the shared volume and a script picks up your wars and deploys to tomcat webapps
- Comes with a standard user 'admin' so as to access manager GUI.
- Available on public docker repo: `docker run -p 8080:8080 -d --name tom -v <YOUR_VOLUME>:/usr/local/stagingwebapps wintersoldier/tomcat_ci:1.0`
- Picks up any war files dropped to the shared volume and instantly deploys them to tomcat server with an option to deploy it via GUI as well
- Here is a [sample application](https://github.com/suchiksagar/dockertomcat) with required maven changes & docker file to explore